# How to resolve the missing dependency in AuthServiceProvider of laravel while register passport routes

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5, jenssegers-mongodb

When I'm trying to print laravel routes with following command

`php artisan route:list`

It throws following exception

`[Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException]

  Unresolvable dependency resolving [Parameter #0 [ <required> array $config ]] in class Jenssegers\Mongodb\Connection`

if I remove the passport routes from my boot method then it works fine but of course passport routes are not getting printed.

here is my boot method:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Auth::provider('mongodb', function(Application $app, array $config){
            return new MongoDBUserProvider();
        });

        Passport::routes();

        Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));
        Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));

    }
```

And if i try to 
`dd(DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('collection_name')->get());`
it prints everything fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to remove the `$config` from `Closure` parameters

```
        public function boot()
        {
            $this->registerPolicies();

            Auth::provider('mongodb', function(Application $app){
                return new MongoDBUserProvider();
            });

            Passport::routes();

            Passport::tokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(15));
            Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(30));

        }
```

Comment: no luck
even if I completely remove this line 
`Auth::provider('mongodb', function(Application $app){
                return new MongoDBUserProvider();
            });`